# Set ListView Adapter for ListView that is in a Fragment from an Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I need to set a ListView's Adapter which is located in a Fragment from an Activity. 
I have tried to set the Adapter from the Activity with the code below, but it returns a `NullPointerException`, presumably because the Fragment has not been loaded yet.

```java
    ListView gradeListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.gradeListView);
    gradeListView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, item_list, list_layout, list_input, layout_values));
```

Is there a way to run the above code after the Fragment has loaded in, or a better way of doing this altogether? I have attempted to use a method that would set the Adapter inside the Fragment itself, but I still need to wait for the fragment to be loaded before I instigate it from the Activity or I will still receive a `NullPointerException`. I would also need to put an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` into a bundle, which there is no documentation on how to do so if I was going to use that method.

I have also tried to instigate a method that holds the set adapter code that is located inside the Activity from the Fragment's `onActivityCreated()` method which still returned a `NullPointerException`.

Am I not referencing the ListView element correctly from the Activity or is there a way to wait for the Fragment to load in, so I don't receive an error?

**TabbedActivity.java / Main Parent Activity**

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    // ...

    interpretGrades(retrieveGrades());
}

public void interpretGrades(String input) {
    // take CLASSES~~MAINCLASSDIVIDER~~GRADES
    // turn it into Classes = Classes
    //              Grades = Grades
    final String[] ServerResponse = input.split("~~MAINCLASSDIVIDER~~");
    final String[] Classes = ServerResponse[0].split(";");
    final String[] Grades = ServerResponse[1].split(";");

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> item_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Classes.length; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] ClassSplit = Classes[i].split("-");
        String Period = ClassSplit[0];
        String Class = ClassSplit[1];
        item.put("Period", Period);
        // --.substring(1, --.length())     removes first character from string (in this case, a whitespace from the class name)
        item.put("Class", Class.substring(1, Class.length()));
        item.put("Grade", Grades[i]);

        item_list.add(item);
    }

    String[] list_input = new String[] { "Period", "Class", "Grade" };

    // PUT THE STRING VALUES FROM list_input INTO THE XML LAYOUT VALUES
    int[] layout_values = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, R.id.grade};

    // LISTVIEW LAYOUT (XML FILE)
    int list_layout = grade_list;

    ListView gradeListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.gradeListView);
    gradeListView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, item_list, list_layout, list_input, layout_values));
}
```

**Tab2Pulse.java / Fragment**

```
public class Tab2Pulse extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2chat, container, false);
        return mainView;
    }
}
```

**tab2chat.xml / Fragment Layout**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tab2chat"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/gradeListView"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_tabbed.xml / Main Activity Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="software.endeavor.projectg.TabbedActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/main_gradient"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="12dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/main_gradient"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

        <!--<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp">-->

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

        <!--</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@*android:dimen/navigation_bar_height"
        android:background="@drawable/login_gradient" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: if your listview is on your fragment and your data are on the activity and you need to fill the listview by the activities' data,you can make a public field on activity and then access them via `(("your activity name") getActivity()).field_name` .

Comment: @alisamawi I get a NullPointerException even if I set it from the Fragment itself.

Comment: can you put your code here to check it myself.

Comment: @alisamawi I've added it to the post.

Comment: Initialize your fragment in the Fragment class (`onViewCreated` or `onActivityCreated`), not in the Activity class. You can pass the required data from the Activity via an interface or `Tab2Pulse` class itself.

Comment: @Naetmul I'm not entirely sure what you mean, could you provide an example?